# Does anyone knows better way of optimizing my code?

Tags: javascript, optimization, logic

I have an object `activeRow` which has parameters `prevValue` and `editedValue`

I use `companyDataKeys` as a default keys. So I need to push to the array `logDetailsArray` an object `logDetails` if `prevValue[key] !== editedValue[key]`

Also I push `logDetails` if `prevValue` or `editedValue` is `undefined` which means it has no value or does't exist

```
const prevValues = this.state.activeRow.prevValue
const editedValues = this.state.activeRow.editedValue

Object.keys(this.state.companyDataKeys).forEach((key) => {
  if (prevValues === undefined) {
    logDetails = {
      param: companyDataValue[key],
      prevValue: '',
      editedValue: (editedValues[key] === undefined) ? '' : editedValues[key].toString(),
    }
    logDetailsArray.push(logDetails)
  }
  if (editedValues === undefined) {
    logDetails = {
      param: companyDataValue[key],
      prevValue: (prevValues[key] === undefined) ? '' : prevValues[key].toString(),
      editedValue: '',
    }
    logDetailsArray.push(logDetails)
  }
  if (editedValues !== undefined && prevValues !== undefined) {
    if (prevValues.hasOwnProperty(key) && editedValues.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      if (editedValues[key] !== prevValues[key]) {
        logDetails = {
          param: companyDataValue[key],
          prevValue: prevValues[key].toString(),
          editedValue: editedValues[key].toString(),
        }
        logDetailsArray.push(logDetails)
      }
    } else if (prevValues[key] !== undefined && editedValues[key] !== undefined) {
      logDetails = {
        param: companyDataValue[key],
        prevValue: (prevValues[key] !== undefined) ? prevValues[key].toString() : '',
        editedValue: (editedValues[key] !== undefined) ? editedValues[key].toString() : '',
      }
      logDetailsArray.push(logDetails)
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: any sample input-output data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, this is what you want!

By using `javascript`'s [truthy-falsey](https://j11y.io/javascript/truthy-falsey/) behaviour and `OR` logic, we reduce your long code into this simpler one!

```
const prevValues = this.state.activeRow.prevValue || {};
const editedValues = this.state.activeRow.editedValue || {};

Object.keys(this.state.companyDataKeys).forEach((key) => {
    logDetails = {
        param: companyDataValue[key],
        prevValue: (prevValues[key] || '').toString(),
        editedValue: (editedValues[key] || '').toString(),
    };
    logDetailsArray.push(logDetails);
});
```

Hope, this will help you. Thanks!

Comment: It is definitely helped me! Thank you! I just did some improvement, because it did't covered all cases. However, everything work!